# Create a new mail message

Tags: c#, email, outlook, message

I need to generate a new mail message so that the client just needs to review it and press "Send" on his e-mail client.

My first thougts were about using a "mailto:" URL but that has strong limitations, e.g., I can't have more than N characters.

What is the best way to do this? Most likely the client will have Outlook or Outlook Express but I'm quite reluctant of using automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mailto is the only way we've found to do this in a platform independent manner, and even at that the mailto string needs to be tailored for specific clients.

Otherwise you are looking at automation, which is client specific and that's where the client supports automation.

Sorry I can't be of more help.